# How to Change the "licensed to" user in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to change the user shown on the VS2012 splash screen next to "licensed to"  - its an OCD thing.

I am on Windows 8 Pro with VS2012 Professional.

I have found some help online that tells me to:

```
Open Registry Editor (Start->Run->type “regedit”->press enter)
Find the following key: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Registration\UserName
Change it’s value to the desired name
Navigate to the following folder: C:\Users\{YOUR_USER}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0 (replace the placeholder with your own username)
Delete the file vs000223.dat – this is actually a JPG file containing the splash screen, you can change it’s name to see it for yourself
Start Visual Studio, and it magically recreates the file with the modified name in it!
```

So I have followed these steps and changed the registry keys (including the Windows NT ones) and then it say's to delete the vs000223.dat file. However, this file doesnt exist, within the C:\Users{YOUR_USER}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0 folder there is only one dat file - ObjBrowEx.dat - but deleting this does nothing - it gets re-created. I have done a search and there is no vs000223.dat

I have even tried running devenv /setup - but that doesn't help.

I have deleted the splashhash registry binary entry, but that didnt work either.

I am clearly missing something, or doing things in the wrong order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alt>Tools>Folder Options > View > SHow Hidden Files and folders.

Look in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0".

Comment: There's the file on my PC as well.

Comment: Yes I have checked there, its no where to be found. I have check in program files, for 32 and 64

Comment: Are you showing hidden files and folders? And ProgramDATA, not Program Files?

Comment: @MarkHall fixed it for you.

Comment: @PectusExcavatum It is located in the ProgramData directory not the Program directory on my computer, it is a hidden file.

Answer (score 4):

Through the registry. I just tested and it worked on Windows Pro 8.1.

> 1. Open Registry Editor (Start->Run->type “regedit”->press enter)
> 2. Find the following key:
>      `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Registration\UserName`
> 3. Change it’s value to the desired name
> 4. Navigate to the following folder:
>      `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`
>      (replace the placeholder with your own username)
> 5. Delete the file `vs000223.dat` (hidden file) – this is actually a JPG file
>      containing the splash screen, you can change it’s name to see it for
>      yourself
> 6. Start Visual Studio, and it magically recreates the file with the
>      modified name in it!

**EDIT :** Path of the file vs000223.dat` updated. It changed since Windows 8.

Source [here](https://superuser.com/questions/498295/how-can-i-change-the-licensed-to-in-visual-studio).

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, the registry path is changed to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices`